# Add a set of images after a specific text in a word file with Python docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I have a set of images in a folder and I am trying to insert them into a word file. Each image has a number as an indicator and I want to insert them right after a specific tag I put in the document. The thing is Pyton's docx is only adding the images at the end of the document.

This is the portion of the code where I add the images:

```
for par in doc.paragraphs:
   tag='[First set of images]')
   if tag in par.text:
       doc.add_picture(alt_file+'\\'+imgs[1],width=Cm(22.51))
       doc.save(docs[1])enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number is in a paragraph by itself, you can add a picture in a run following the text (but still in the same paragraph) like this:

```
if tag in paragraph.text:
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    run.add_picture("image.png", ...)
```

The details of the `Run.add_picture()` call are in the API documentation here:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#run-objects

Comment: @JuanG Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't neglect to accept the answer to your question. That's how you show appreciation for the time the respondent took to create the answer and it also builds your own reputation points. Just click on the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it.